# how to extract a character out of string in a column with 100k rows

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column x that has 100k rows is as follows:

x

DIV.CDN

DIV.XYN

VIM.NGN

VIM.AHY

I need to extract the 3rd character from the dot(.) to the right, for example:
N

N

N

Y

How to do it Pandas dataframe?

Comment: Please fix your data.  You give 4 inputs but only 3 outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `str` accessor:

```
>>> df
         x
0  DIV.CDN
1  DIV.XYN
2  VIM.NGN
3  VIM.AHY

>>> df['x'].str[-1]
0    N
1    N
2    N
3    Y
Name: x, dtype: object
```

Please, read the documentation: [Working with text data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that each column value is a string, for each one you can grab it with a simple index:

```
third_character = string[-1]
```

Here, it is essentially grabbing the last element of the string. In order to do it over all of the rows, one option is to implement a for-loop that iteratively does this over all rows, appending to a list each time.